# Why does it take so long time to process the async await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, async-await

I made my express application with the async+await.
However it took so long time to finish this task.

```
async.parallel(
  {
    cars: function (callback) {
      Car.findById(req.params.id).exec(callback);
    },
  },
  async (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      var paramsDel = { Bucket: "test-s3-may", Key: results.cars.image_id };

      s3.deleteObject(paramsDel, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          console.log("go to the next step"); //lineA
        });
      });

      var updated_car = await Car.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, car, {});
      res.redirect(updated_car.url);
    }
  }
);
```

When I proceed this code, lineA(console.log("go to the next step) is displayed instantly.
After that, I have to wait almost 1-2 minutes for redirect commands.

Is it the problem of await? I'm sure that my internet speed is fast enough to upload any file.

Comment: You should move the two lines starting with `var updated_car = await Car.findByIdAndUpdate` immediately after the `console.log` call if you want them to wait for the `upload` call to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the issue lies with the upload process, but following you method signature:

```
Car.findByIdAndUpdate
```

it seems rather to be local data storage based update call.

`await` is nothing but a syntactic sugar around `Promise`(s) with which you can write plain imperative statements in the old fashioned way and don't have to chain you completion `callback` into `#then`.

Thereby, `await`ed statement call will still cause the function to be paused *in a non-blocking way* until the underlying promise finishes (either fulfills or rejects).

In other words, the runtime is not blocked and further requests can be processed but the `res.redirect(updated_car.url);` won't be executed until the `Car.findByIdAndUpdate` function is resolved **which thus needs to be profiled based on your storage system**.

Comment: Thanks much, this helped me to understand the problem :)